# Delete array Session::forget() Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to delete 1 array `Session::push('product', $array);` ex: when click button remove (x), session will delete array[0] and `Session::push('product', $array);` just still array[1]

```
"product" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => "9"
      "name" => "Điện thoại Samsung Galaxy A5 2016"
      "price" => "888888990"
      "picture" => "16046_315945335227228_2087086595407127217_n.jpg"
      "qty" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => "10"
      "name" => "Điện thoại Samsung Galaxy A5 2016"
      "price" => "888888990"
      "picture" => "16046_315945335227228_2087086595407127217_n.jpg"
      "qty" => "1"
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// Get the product array
$product = Session::get('product');

// Unset the first index (or provide an index)
unset($product[0]);

// Overwrite the product session
Session::put('product', $product);
```